# Help with the following words in a sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses

Hi should I say "I am declaring [a country] my children and I’s ordinarily resident country" or should I use another phrase for "my children and I's" ?

Thank you

Comment: This has been covered many, many times before. [50+ times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4226?lq=1), in fact. Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Our country of residence is...."

"My family's normal country of residence is...."

"Normal country of residence for me and my children is...."